# Cannot install libzmq3-dev on ubuntu 19.04

Tags: zeromq, failed-installation, ubuntu-19.04

I'm trying to install `libzmq3-dev` on **Ubuntu 19.04**, using the command:

```
sudo apt install build-essential libsocketcan-dev libzmq3-dev
```

I get the message:

```
> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:  

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  
 libzmq3-dev : Depends: libpgm-dev (>= 5.2.122~dfsg) but it is not installable
               Depends: libsodium-dev but it is not installable
               Depends: libnorm-dev but it is not installable
               Depends: libkrb5-dev but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages'
```

Any ideas?